# R: How to interpret my party plot decision tree?

Tags: r, data-mining, decision-tree

I made a decision tree with party plot in R but don't really know what it's telling me. The data is about the indian startup ecosystem. **I don't know what nodes mean.**

Comment: The nodes are a decision, with the name of the variable used for the decision plotted in it.

Comment: I still don't understand unfortunately. Could you describe what it's saying about the likeliness of investment?

Answer (score 0):

The tree displays the subsets found through recursive partitioning. The dependent variable in every resulting subset is visualized by a box plot.

As an example, consider node 10:

- There are 95 observations in this subset.
- These are all the observations which used "seed funding" as the `InvestmantnType` *and* had a `Date.dd.mm.yyyy` in 15, 2018, or 2019.
- The boxplot shows the distribution of the dependent variable `Amount.in.USD` for these 95 observations.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I used log and got the above result! Still not sure what it is saying though.

Comment: OK, thanks, I adapted my response. The question still claims that the response is binary, though. The label Data.dd.mm.yyyy also seems to be misleading because it appears to be the years only. Finally, Date.dd.mm.yyyy = 15 might be a coding error.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the variable importance from `tree$variable.importance` or you can simply `summary(tree)`. Variable importance tells us which variables are most important for the models to make decisions.